# Cloning a row in a table with indexes, autonumber and default fields

Tags: sql-server, clone, cloning

Building a new system on MsSQL from an old MySQL setup, we come to find that several times, a row is clonned in DRAFT version before it gets PUBLISHED, short of data preparation.

This is done in several tables that have autoincrement fields (ID) and defaults (timestamp, and so on)

As today, this is done with something like

```
Insert into MyTable (Status, CustomerID, CName, Csurname, <all other fields>
  SELECT 'DRAFT', CustomerID, CName, Csurname, <all other fields>
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE CustomerID = 1234
```

For a table as:

```
MyTable : ID, timestamp, Status, CustomerID, CName, Csurname, <all other fields>
```

the problem, each time a new column is added to the table, SPs need to be rewritten

**would be any better strategy??**

We tough on an function, that given a table name, and the "Key fields" (the where) and the Changed fields with the new values (the Status field in the example), it goes trough the table definition, and build the SQL sentence, looking for all fields except those autonumber (ID) and those that have a default (timestamp).

But before come into such a weird code, I would like some feedback form the community.

Comment: looks like you need `Dynamic SQL`

Comment: When the schema changes, the insert or update code needs to change.  This can either be done manually like you might be doing now or thru dynamic T-SQL that creates an interface (stored procedure).  Make sure you assign privileges at the schema level or use ALTER PROCEDURE.  The later keeps the current permissions on the STORED PROCEDURE.

Comment: @Squirrel thanks for response, yes, that I mean, a function with Dinamic SQL seems the only option ..

Comment: @CRAFTYDBA seems to you a SP better than a function?? (I got the understanding, simplifying a lot, that SP for data changes, FUNCTIONS when data doesn't change, sure, that's oversimplification)

Comment: If you have a multi-line function, it is considered a black box by the optimizer.  On the other hand, a stored procedure is compiled and broken down into plans by the optimizer.  In short, functions are typically slower.  You experience may vary depending upon your environment.